# How to automate ElectronJS app

Tags: javascript, automation, electron, puppeteer, nightmare

We're looking to develop an ElectronJS app for particular website automation at our desk job, which includes common tasks like login, form filling, report downloading etc.

We've tried basic tutorial of ElectronJS, Spectron, NightmareJS, Puppeteer etc and all of them work fine separately, but very less documentation (although open github issues) are available on integration of each other.

We want to achieve following:

- Login state (`session`) should not be deleted on ElectronJS app closing and should be available on restart of app.
- Few menu buttons which initiates some automation tasks like download, form fill etc on existing `browserWindow`

We don't need headless automation, where some magic happens behind the scene. We need menu/button click based actions/tasks on current page only.

`NightmareJS`, `Puppeteer` etc all seems to start their own instances of web pages (since because they were built for testing of standalone apps) but what we need is automation of existing `BrowserWindows`.

Is `puppeteer` or `nightmarejs` correct tools for such goals? If yes, any documentation?

Or else, should we inject our own native JS events like `mouseclick` etc events in console to perform action?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `puppeteer-core`. `core` version by default does not download Chromium, which you do not need if you want to control an Electron app.

In the test you then call `launch` method, where you define `electron` as the executable file instead of Chromium, like in following snippet:

```
const electron = require("electron");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");

const delay = ms =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, ms);
  });

(async () => {
  try {
    const app = await puppeteer.launch({
      executablePath: electron,
      args: ["."],
      headless: false,
    });
    const pages = await app.pages();
    const [page] = pages;

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1200, height: 700 });
    await delay(5000);
    const image = await page.screenshot();
    console.log(image);
    await page.close();
    await delay(2000);
    await app.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

Update for electron 5.x.y and up (currently up to 7.x.y, I did not test it on 8.x.y beta yet), where `puppeteer.connect` is used instead of `launch` method:

```
// const assert = require("assert");
const electron = require("electron");
const kill = require("tree-kill");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

let pid;

const run = async () => {
  const port = 9200; // Debugging port
  const startTime = Date.now();
  const timeout = 20000; // Timeout in miliseconds
  let app;

  // Start Electron with custom debugging port
  pid = spawn(electron, [".", `--remote-debugging-port=${port}`], {
    shell: true
  }).pid;

  // Wait for Puppeteer to connect
  while (!app) {
    try {
      app = await puppeteer.connect({
        browserURL: `http://localhost:${port}`,
        defaultViewport: { width: 1000, height: 600 } // Optional I think
      });
    } catch (error) {
      if (Date.now() > startTime + timeout) {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }

  // Do something, e.g.:
  // const [page] = await app.pages();
  // await page.waitForSelector("#someid")// 
  // const text = await page.$eval("#someid", element => element.innerText);
  // assert(text === "Your expected text");
  // await page.close();
};

run()
  .then(() => {
    // Do something
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Do something
    kill(pid, () => {
      process.exit(1);
    });
  });
```

Getting the `pid` and using `kill` is optional. For running the script on some CI platform it does not matter, but for local environment you would have to close the electron app manually after each failed try.

Simple demo repo:
https://github.com/peterdanis/electron-puppeteer-demo

Comment: Hello Peter, does this mean I can script user interaction inside the Electron application? How does it know how to launch Electron and place necessary script inside the Electron app? Are the Electron CLI flags similar to Chromium CLI flags then?

Comment: Hi Joe. Exactly! You can control page living inside Electron (in the renderer process). It controls the Electron app in the same way as it does control Chromium - through DevTools protocol. Regarding launching the right executable - in the example above I pass in Electron's path instead of Chromium in the launch method. I did not try yet to use it for e2e testing of final built app, but it should probably work in the same way.

Comment: I get this error: `The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object` at `puppeteer-core/lib/Launcher.js:126:40`

Comment: @PeterDanis: I have been testing your solution without success.  Your proposition is coherent... But have you made this working or can you provide a repo where we can use your working solution ?

Comment: @Alain - sorry for late reply. Please check simple demo repo: https://github.com/peterdanis/electron-puppeteer-demo

Comment: @PeterDanis: Your git repo works, when adding a delay between the .launch() (with shell) and and the .connect(), otherwise, the page is not always set. I wish to add a plus to this response, however, your git repo and this answer do not match ! Finally with the git repo, I was able to create a screenshot of the page. I am not sure if the DevsTool protocol is fully supported by electron.

Answer (score 1):

**Automation Script in Java using Selenium and ChromeDriver**

```
package setUp;

import helper.Constants;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;


public class Test {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

             System.setProperty(Constants.WebDriverType, Constants.WebDriverPath + Constants.WindowsDriver);

             ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();

             DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

             capabilities.setCapability("chromeOptions", opt);
             capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
             capabilities.setVersion("73.0.3683.121");

             ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
             options.merge(capabilities);
             options.setBinary("C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Audio\\\\Audio-Configuration\\\\Audio-Configuration.exe");
             options.setCapability("chromeOptions", options);
             ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

             try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                                 "/html/body/app-root/mat-drawer-container/mat-drawer/div/app-bottom-side-nav/div/app-settings-nav/div/div/a/div"));                        
                    webElement.click();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception trace");
                    System.out.println(e);
             }
       }
}
```

---

**Automation Script in JavaScript using Spectron** (built on top-of ChromeDriver and WebDriverIO).

```
const Application = require("spectron").Application;

const path =
  "C:/Program Files/Audio/Audio-Configuration/Audio-Configuration.exe";
const myApp = new Application({
  path: path,
  chromeDriverArgs: ["--disable-extensions"],
  env: {
    SPECTRON: true,
    ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING: true,
    ELECTRON_ENABLE_STACK_DUMPING: true
  }
});

const windowClick = async app => {
  await app.start();
  try {
    // Identifying by class name
    await app.client.click(".ic-setting");

    // Identifying by Id
    // await app.client.click("#left-btn");
  } catch (error) {
    // Log any failures
    console.error("Test failed", error.message);
  }
  // Stop the application
     await app.stop();
};

windowClick(myApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Spectron is the best match for electron build applications.

You will have access to all electron API.we can start and stop your app by spectron only.

We can run both packaged app or with out even packaging.

https://electronjs.org/spectron

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spectron but if you want to look at documentation, Spectron is using [webdriverio](http://webdriver.io/) which has good documentation.

I recommend you to use Spectron because I tried to automate my tests with java-selenium but it fails some of case. If you want to use selenium, write below code to set capabilities to setup electron app to chromedriver.

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary(binaryPath);
    options.addArguments("--app=" + argPath);
    options.setCapability("chromeOptions", options);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Hope this will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

If integrating with electron nightmare is a very good library to achieve this even it will be ready to distribute with it, here is the following useful documentation for the same [resource1](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#api)
and